# Как растянуть высоту элементов, находящихся внутри div?

Tags: html, css

Добрый день.
Есть n-количество элементов div в родительском элементе div с высотой, скажем 600px.
Как мне с помощью css разместить дочерние элементы по одинаковой высоте?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Или вы что-то недосказали, или я действительно не вижу проблемы:

1. [Делаем с помощью float](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/m33zfgac/)
2. [С помощью inline-block](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/m33zfgac/1/). Дочерние блоки - резиновые по ширине
3. [Аналогично второму пункту](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/m33zfgac/2/), но резиновые и по ширине, и по высоте с ограничением "max-height: 600px;"
4. [Аналогично третьему пункту](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/m33zfgac/3/), но с использованием свойств: display: table и table-cell;

Comment: Дело в том,что здесь указывается по 33% на 3 элемента. А я на момент разметки не знаю, сколько элементов будет в родительским div. Хочется что б высота делилась поровну на количество элементов

Comment: @Роман Ракзин, проценты только для примера, [можно обойтись и без них][1]. Но судя по последнему предложения, я так понимаю, что вы хотите разместить элементы по вертикали и разделить высоту "родителя" поровну на все дочерние? Если именно такой вариант вам нужен, то можно использовать **flexbox**. [Смотрите пример][2].

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/m33zfgac/6/
   [2]:http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/m33zfgac/7/

Comment: Спасибо. Да. Это то,что нужно.